# Tensorflow.keras error using Conv2D input depth and filter depth are not compatible?

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I'm using tensorflow 2.1 and getting this error

```
OP_REQUIRES failed at conv_ops.cc:530 : Invalid argument: input depth must be evenly divisible by filter depth: 56 vs 16
```

When I run this code

```
# modified from https://github.com/tensorflow/tpu/blob/master/models/official/efficientnet/efficientnet_model.py
def SEBlock(input_filters, se_ratio, data_format=None):

    expand_ratio = 1
    num_reduced_filters = max(
        1, int(input_filters * se_ratio))
    filters = input_filters * expand_ratio

    channel_axis = -1
    spatial_dims = [1, 2]

    def block(inputs):
        x = inputs
        x = layers.Lambda(lambda a: K.mean(a, axis=spatial_dims, keepdims=True))(x)
        x = layers.Conv2D(
            num_reduced_filters,
            kernel_size=[1, 1],
            strides=[1, 1],
            padding='same',
            use_bias=True,
            data_format="channels_last")(x)
        x = Swish()(x)
        # Excite
        x = layers.Conv2D(
            filters,
            kernel_size=[1, 1],
            strides=[1, 1],
            padding='same',
            use_bias=True,
            data_format="channels_last")(x)
        x = layers.Activation('sigmoid')(x)
        out = layers.Multiply()([x, inputs])
        return out

    return block
```

When I build my model with this block it builds just fine, but when I try to train it blows up.
The input tensor to the block is of `shape=(None, 56, 56, 16)`, the output returns a tensor with the same dimensions.

```
input_filters = 16
se_ratio = .25
```

Comment: Could you make a complete example, something runnable?

Comment: Also what is `K.mean`. I'm surprised the graph compiles with the Multiply() where filters is 4, giving x a filter dimension of 4 and the inputs filter dimension of 16.

Comment: ^filters is 16 and K.mean is just global average pooling its returning (None,1,1,16) and I can't provide the code, but I narrowed down the problem to the Multiply function. It is somehow rotating the values in the tensor around. Ex.) it tries to multiply (2,16,1,1) and (2,56,16,56) tensors. If I take Multiply out, then the tensors go back to normal (batch,rows,cols,channels). Multiply should be multiplying x = (2,1,1,16) and inputs=(2,56,56,16) when i use a batch size of 2. When i print out the model architecture it shows this behavior, but during training the values are getting moved around

Comment: Oh I see, you have expand ratio, and se_ration. What is K though, if this is tensorflow 2.1 you probably shouldn't be using K, as in `from keras import backend as K` you can replace it with tensorflow.math.reduce_mean. It's possible you're mixing keras/api changes but it is hard to tell.

Comment: Right now I have it as `import tensorflow.keras.backend as K` but that’s a good point. I’ll switch it out and post back 

Comment: Replaced all of the keras.backend calls with tf but it's still reshaping the inputs during training. I worked around it by adding tf.reshape but I still don't know what's causing it.

Comment: Did you try the answer I posted with your setup to see if it happens in isolation?

Comment: I went through and ran it in isolation using dummy data and it worked perfectly. I isolated the problem to a third party's custom generator I was using during training. By substituting it out with my own it's working without issue. Thank you for your help tracking this down!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a compilable example. If you found a bug, it might something like this could help get it filed. Also, I cannot use the swish activation, so I made a lambda. That could be a difference too.

```
import tensorflow.keras as keras
import tensorflow.math as K

import numpy
ip = keras.layers.Input((56, 56, 16))
x = keras.layers.Lambda(lambda a: K.reduce_mean(a, axis=[1,2], keepdims=True))(ip)
x = keras.layers.Conv2D( 
    4, 
    kernel_size=[1,1], 
    strides=[1,1], 
    padding='same', 
    use_bias=True,
    data_format="channels_last" )(x)
x = keras.layers.Lambda(lambda a: a*K.sigmoid(a))(x)
x = keras.layers.Conv2D( 
    16, 
    kernel_size=[1,1], 
    strides=[1,1], 
    padding='same', 
    use_bias=True,
    data_format="channels_last" )(x)

x = keras.layers.Activation('sigmoid')(x)
x = keras.layers.Multiply()([x, ip])
m = keras.Model(inputs=[ip], outputs=[x])


y = m.predict(numpy.random.random((2, 56, 56, 16)))

print(y.shape)
```